# Why do we need to use PWM to control a DC motor on a microcontroller but the same DC motors work when plugged directly into batteries?

Tags: dc-motor

For example, just powering an Arduino pin connected to a motor doesn't turn on the motor.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about the current needed to drive that motor? I don't know which motor, so I can't tell if this is an issue, but motors are typically a bit beefier on the current so the MCU is not able to supply it. You wouldn't need PWM if the current is low enough.

Comment: The example in the body of your question has no direct relationship to your title.  Did you perhaps mean to ask why you need to use a **driver circuit**?

Comment: There is no question here.  And no, titles are not relevant in describing the question.  Titles are meant to give a quick idea what the question is about, not a extended description.  -1 for making it a hassle for everyone, and voting to close because this isn't a proper question.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need PWM to drive a DC motor. As you've seen, you can simply connect it to an adequate power source.

An Arduino pin is not an adequate power source for most motors, but it can be used to control a transistor or a relay which acts as a switch to connect or disconnect power to the motor.

What PWM gives you is the ability to vary the power delivered to the motor, and thus its speed (and often direction) rather than simply on/off control, under the control of your Arduino.